# Sample swift code for Yelp 2.0 API

Tags: ios, swift, rest, oauth-2.0, yelp

I'm a naive developer trying my hand on Swift. I'm trying to find some code samples / tutorials / for using Yelp search ( 2.0 ) api call using Swift. I think I can use NSURLSession for rest call but not sure how to make oauth work.

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/codepath/ios_yelp_swift or Google it.